How do I get pyright to complain about unused functions/methods/classes?
My pyright tells me when a variable inside a function is unused (specifically it says foo is not accessed). However, it doesn't tell me when anything else is unused, as far as I've tested.
How can I get it to tell me when other things (like classes, functions, and variables outside of functions) are unused?
Everything I've found online regarded changing the way unused variables are displayed or disabling this feature, neither of which are what I want.
My config is at github.com/L3ec/nvim-again.

This  has nothing to do with Vim (or, probably, Neovim). Start with the doc/issue tracker of whatever it is you have that is interfacing with Pyright.

I'm not sure pyright has that functionality.
I suppose you should first check with pyright support if that functionality is supported.
If so check with the LSP bridge (coc.nvim) if it can be used to Grey out some classes or methods.
